# Как обратиться к стороннему сайту и получать ответ без API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Есть сайт нейронки, [BAI Chat](https://chatbot.theb.ai/). Хочу получать ответы на запросы, не заходя на него.
Допустим, у меня есть на моем сайте какое то поле, я нажимаю кнопку, в поле возвращается результат (ответ чата).
Реально ли это сделать без API ?

На одном ресурсе мне посоветовали сделать следующее:

> Сделать POST запрос на https://chatbot.theb.ai/api/chat-process с пейлоадом в виде `{"prompt":"what are u?","options":{}}`, получаешь ответ в виде base64 строки. Декодируешь её и читаешь последний объект (там несовсем джейсон, поэтому сплитишь и берёшь последний `.split('\n').at(-1)` и потом уже его парсишь в джейсон).

Я не силен в программировании, но написал на Jquery следующий код запроса:

```js
$('#test').click(function(){  
  $.post(
    "https://chatbot.theb.ai/api/chat-process",
    {
      "prompt": "what are u?",
      "options": {}
    },
    function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }  
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

В консоль возвращается такая строка:

> {"message":"Message is empty","data":null,"status":"Fail"}

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учтите, [данный API сервис платный](https://theb.ai/resources/pricing.html), есть дневной лимит на использование - 30 мин

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://chatbot.theb.ai/api/chat-process',
    type: 'post',
    // json превращаем в строку запроса
    data: JSON.stringify({
      options: {},
      prompt: "what are u?"
    }),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно работает, но мне интересно в чем моя ошибка? Дело в том, что я вчера пробовал тоже через метод $.ajax( ). Код был следущий:

Comment: $.ajax({
      url:"https:chatbot.theb.ai/api/chat-process",
      type:"POST",
      headers: { 
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;",
      },
      data:{ "prompt": "какой сейчас год?", "options": {} },
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(data){
        console.log( data );
      }
    })

У меня выдавало в консоли "has been blocked by CORS policy".  Я так понимаю всё дело в JSON.stringify ?

Comment: @ИванОрлов да, если отправлять без JSON.stringify то пустой параметр options скипается и запрос без него улетает